# Excel formula to SUBSTITUTE value with specific parameters

Tags: excel, formula

I have formula to convert text "2 **hours** 43 mins" to "2,43". Sometimes value is "1 **hour** 43 mins" and my current solution does not work in this case. How to make it work in both cases "2 **hours** 43 mins" and "1 **hour** 43 mins"? I have tried to use OR with no success.

This is my current formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q68;"mins";"");" hours ";",")
```

I have tried:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q68;"mins";"");OR(" hours ";" hour ");",")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q68;"s";"");"min";"");" hour ";",")
```

Comment: Both works. Ricardo has less reputation and was a little bit faster so I mark this as an answer :)

Comment: @user7202022 I agree!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Q68;"min";"");" hour";",");"s";"")
```

**EDIT#1:**

The "best approach":

1. replace "hour"
2. replace "min"
3. replace "s"
4. replace " "

Comment: Just for the sake of giving alternatives: `=LEFT(Q68,(FIND(" ",Q68,1)-1))&":"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(Q68," ";REPT(" ",100)),200,100))` :)